# double alert on a click naviganting index array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get 2 alert when I click on the sub menu, the pop up first says 1 and then a second pop up gives me 2. I would like the alert to be 0,1,2,3 etc in correct sequence as per navigating an array. Is it not the sub menu item just the following item in an array?

```
<ul id="menu">
   <li><a href="page1">Item 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="page2">Item 2</a> 
      <ul id="sub-menu">
           <li><a href="page3">Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="page4">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Jquery:

```
jQuery (function($) {
  $("#menu .menu li").each(function (index) {
     var item = $(this);
     $("a", item).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert(index);
     });
  });
});
```

Comment: I am trying to understand what you mean by displaying alert in sequence... For example: How do you want the alert to be displayed when I click on Item 3 (3rd link)?

Comment: I can't see you are actually using the `menu` class. Rather than that, a selector `#menu .menu` doesn't make much sense. Give it a thought.

Comment: @Alexander ye sorry haven't put the classes, was a quick example. I understand it could have been confusing. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way without using `event.stopPropagation()`:

```
jQuery (function($) {
  $("#menu .menu li").each(function (index) {
    var item = $(this);
    $("> a", item).click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert(index);
    });
  });
});​
```

It will only trigger for the immediate child of `li`.

Here is the [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/DKe6n/).

Comment: Perfect. that's what I was neeeding. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I thought you wanted the index relative to the nearest enclosing ul:
http://jsfiddle.net/mari/68Zjt/

Comment: nope, the verified answer is what I was looking for but yours can be useful too, thanks a lot